# NSDateFormatter not encoding 24 hour in japanese as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

i'm using the following code to get a parseable date/time to send to our server:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"YMMddHHmmss"];
NSLog([dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]]);
```

Below is the date the gets output from the log line when using the "Japanese" region settings.

The Japanese characters that are not digits below translate to "morning" which I assume is some type of am/pm modifier

`2013-12-12午前10-07-23`

the HH string in my formatter should be forcing the date formatter to remove such modifiers so i'm a bit confused as to why im seeing that "morning" text.

I think I can solve this issue by simple always setting the locale of the date formatter object to en_US_POSIX.  Anything wrong with this approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes and it does seem to fix the issue.  I just wanted to make sure this is the correct approach.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the 12/24 "feature" (a bug that Apple had declared to not be a bug) -- if the 12/24 setting on the phone is set contrary to the locale you get this.  The solution is to use one of the several locales that suppress this behavior, such as en_US_POSIX.  I know of no other fix, other than to manually format the date with NSDateComponents, etc.

Comment: It looks like this date formatting issue started happening with iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: When executing your code, iam getting the output 20131223112656??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue did start happening as of iOS 7.0.4.  Prior to that release date from the Japanese locale were converting fine.  Setting the locale of the NSDateFormatter to en_US_POSIX before converting the date does fix it in iOS 7.0.4